# How to configure custom Lightning component as subtab of patient using patient card configuration

Tags: lightning, health-cloud

How to configure custom Lightning component as subtab of patient using patient card configuration

Using Customize the Patient Card Navigation Menu and Patient Subtabs we can configure to open custom VF and URL in HC patient card.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.health_cloud.meta/health_cloud/admin_card_view_menu.htm

I am configuring HC in Lightning console so don't want use to VF page in tab. but i am not able to configure lightning component/tab/app/page in HC. Need help to configure custom Lightning component/tab/app/page.

Comment: please share your code